# pandas how to perform comparison on column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find all the rows in which the coulmn `two` values are in between `1.5` and `3.5`.  The result I am expecting is row with index 1 and 2. I tried the following code but getting an error.

```
>>> d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
...  'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.],
... 'three':['a','b','c','d']}
>>> d
{'three': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'two': [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0], 'one': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}
>>> DataFrame(d)
   one three  two
0    1     a    4
1    2     b    3
2    3     c    2
3    4     d    1
>>> df = DataFrame(d)
>>> df[1.5 <= df['two'] <= 3.5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do chained comparisons with numpy (and therefore pandas). Do instead:

```
df[(1.5 <= df.two) & (df.two <= 3.5)]
```

Comment: Thanks Worked as desired

Comment: Every comparison operation on a Series object creates a new boolean Series and the only way to do an `and`, or an `or` operation between a Series is using the `&` and `|` binary operators. After that you can do a regular boolean indexing.

Answer (score 8):

Sort of a non-answer but I thought I would share anyway

In pandas==0.13 (next major release) you'll be able to do the following

```
df['1.5 <= two <= 3.5']
# or use the query method
df.query('1.5 <= two <= 3.5')
```

Under the hood this uses the `pd.eval` function, which rewrites chained comparisons as how you would usually write them and then passes the resulting string to `numexpr`. It also "attaches" the columns (and the index and the column index) in the `DataFrame` to a namespace specific to the query (this is controllable by the user, but it defaults to the aforementioned elements). You'll also be able to use the `and`, `or` and `not` keywords in the way that you use the `&`, `|` and `~` bitwise operators in standard Python.

Comment: I should say that my use of the attach terminology is from R.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) ?

```
df[df.two.between(1.5, 3.5)]
```